# How do I put loops at an angle in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm trying to draw a graph in TikZ that has self-loops, and I'd like to be able to specify their position not only as "right" or "above", but something like "above right", i.e. at a 45° angle.

How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome! Not sure if I understand you correctly, but are you looking for something like that shown in the first example of section 51.4, "Loops", of the PGF (v. 2.10) manual? (`\node [circle,draw] {a} edge [in=30,out=60,loop] ();`)

Comment: That's it! Many thanks @torbjorn-t!

Comment: No problem. I added it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 17):

There is an example in the [`pgf`/TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (for `pgf` v.3.0.0 dated December 20 2013, section **70.4 Loops**) that demonstrates this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle,draw] {a} edge [in=30,out=60,loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]