# put a label inside loop made by path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am completely new to `tikz` so excuse me if it seems easy.
I am going to put a label inside the closed path I have written(mostly taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45806/tikzpicture-how-can-i-draw-a-loop-right-below)):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
                thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\Large\bfseries}]
  \node[main node] (2) {2};
  \node[main node] (1) [below left  of=2] {1};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right of=2] {3};
  \path
    (1) edge node [below]{} (2)
        edge node[below] {} (3)     
    (2) edge node[right] {} (3)
    (3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Thanks for any guide.

Comment: Your code is not compileable. It must start with the `\document{class}` and end with the `\document{document}`.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add the text?

Comment: @AndréC just in the middle of three nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know which "*center*" you're talking about, I suggest you use the barycentric coordinates to do so. *(See pages 136 et seq. of manual 3.1
13.2.2 Barycentric Systems)*

[image: barycentre]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
                thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\Large\bfseries}]
  \node[main node] (2) {2};
  \node[main node] (1) [below left  of=2] {1};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right of=2] {3};
  \path
    (1) edge node [below]{} (2)
        edge node[below] {} (3)     
    (2) edge node[right] {} (3)
    (3) ;
  \node at (barycentric cs:1=1,2=1 ,3=1) {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

off-topic:

- use only numbers for node names is not good practice. instead `1`, `2` and `3` is better to use for example `n1`, or `n2` and `n3`
- if you not label edges than don't clutter code with empty nodes.
- for labeling of edges is handy to use `quotes` library
- at using `barycentric` coordinates be careful: between colon or comas and node names had not be an empty space
- it seems that you have a mess in code for drawing arrows

using solution for placing nodes inside triangle suggested in @AndréC answer (+1) the *mwe* can be as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           node distance = 17.3mm and 10mm,
       every edge/.style = {draw, semithick, -Stealth, shorten >=1pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {inner sep=1pt,
                            font=\footnotesize, text=gray,
                            sloped, auto=left},
             main/.style = {circle, draw, semithick,
                            minimum size=3ex, inner sep=2pt,
                            font=\bfseries}
                        ]
\node (n1) [main] {1};
\node (n2) [main, above right=of n1] {2};
\node (n3) [main, below right=of n2] {3};

% note: between ":" or "," and "<node name>" had not to be empty space!
\node at (barycentric cs:n1=1 ,n2=1 ,n3=1) {text};

\draw   (n1) edge ["2" ']    (n3)
        (n1) edge ["3"]      (n2)
        (n2) edge ["1"]      (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]