# How to draw loop with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, mathematics

How can I draw loop? I want to draw this graph with tikz, but I can't.[image]

Comment: 1. Read both tikz manuals. 2. Draw nodes A and B. 3. Draw lines from A to B, vice versa, and from A to A, and B to B, using options in and out. Find all these in #1.

Comment: Search for automatas...

Comment: @MS-SPO Both TikZ manuals? There's more than one?

Comment: Look at for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45806/tikzpicture-how-can-i-draw-a-loop-right-below, that should give you some inspiration. Edit: and look at the tutorials in chapters 2-6 of the TikZ manual.

Comment: At ctan you’ll find a minimal introduction, which gives you a quick overview. The huge manual starts with several tutorials. Equipped with this information you’ll find what‘s relevant more easily in the huge one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of example that looks very alike what you're looking for. Here's one with states named inside of nodes.

[image: automata with loop]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=Stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,semithick]
         \tikzset{every state/.style={draw=black,text=black}}
        
         \node[state] (0)               {A};
         \node[state] (1)  [right of=0] {B};
        
         \path (0) edge [loop left]  node {a} (0)
                   edge [bend left]  node {a} (1)
               (1) edge [loop right] node {b} (1)
                   edge [bend left]  node {b} (0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want your states to be dots, just do it!

[image: v2]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=Stealth,auto,shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,semithick]
         \tikzset{
            mystate/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=4pt},
            myloopleft/.style={out=-140,in=140,looseness=20},
            myloopright/.style={out=40,in=-40,looseness=20}}
        
         \node[mystate,label={above:A}] (0)               {};
         \node[mystate,label={above:B}] (1)  [right of=0] {};
        
         \path (0) edge [myloopleft]  node {a} (0)
                   edge [bend left]  node {a} (1)
               (1) edge [myloopright] node {b} (1)
                   edge [bend left]  node {b} (0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to draw nodes without circle, same as picture.

Comment: Thank you so much.